# Magento 1.9 custom product tabs based on parent category

Tags: product, category, tabs

I have successfully created some custom tabs on my product pages via my local.xml file.  However, I would like to show/hide different tabs based on the parent category of the product.

Can this be done in the local.xml file or do I have to create some if/else statements in my template files?

Any suggestions?

Here is my local.xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

```
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="product.info">
        <block type="core/template" name="safety_data" as="safety_data" template="peptide/safety_data.phtml">
            <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
            <action method="setTitle" translate="value"><value>Safety Data</value></action>
        </block>
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>

<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="product.info">
        <block type="core/template" name="quality_control" as="quality_control" template="peptide/quality_control.phtml">
            <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
            <action method="setTitle" translate="value"><value>Quality Control</value></action>
        </block>
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

Comment: show custom tab code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help and suggestions.

Upon researching the methods further, I ended-up just adding conditionals to my custom phtml files that the local.xml file reference like so:

```
    <?php $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/layer')->getCurrentCategory();?>
<?php if($category->getId()==15): ?>

<h3>Show content for Category ID15</h3>

<?php else: ?>

<h3>Show content for other categories</h3>
<p>consectetuer adipiscing elit. </p>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the magento category handle  in local.xml
but I dont know if that handler is called in product page

You may use the category "Custom Design" to update the layout of the child products

You can found the "Custom Design" tab in the Admin menu Catalog->Manage Categories